# Error invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' usando -fpermissive

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Estou seguindo uma série de vídeo-aulas em C (https://youtu.be/zZlIy3hp0c0?t=10m29s), mas encontrei um problema.

Primeiro eu rodei este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10; 
    int *resultado;
    resultado = &x;

    printf("Valor &x = %d", resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

E então descobri que o valor de resultado (endereço de memória) é de 2358940.

Então tentei fazer da mesma forma que a vídeo-aulas fez:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    int *resultado;
    resultado = 2358940;

    printf("Valor x = %d", *resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

E continuo encontrando o mesmo erro, e fazendo exatamente o que a vídeo-aula fez. Não entendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda vez que você roda o seu programa, o endereço da memória onde a variável `x` estará armazenada é diferente. Portanto, se você roda o programa uma vez, copia o endereço, e tenta rodar o programa novamente, aquele endereço não será mais válido. Se você, durante a execução do mesmo programa, entrar com o valor, essa operação irá funcionar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 10; 
    int *resultado;
    char temp[100];
    int enderecoLido;

    resultado = &x;

    printf("Valor &x = %d\n", resultado);

    printf("Agora digite o valor do endereço de memoria: ");
    gets(temp);
    enderecoLido = atoi(temp);
    printf("Valor digitado: %d\n", enderecoLido);

    resultado = enderecoLido;
    printf("Valor x = %d", *resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

Mas, como disse @Maniero em sua ótima resposta, essa operação (entrar com um endereço arbitrário de memória e tentar interpretá-lo) não é recomendado.

Answer (score 4):

O primeiro código só compila com opções para deixar passar possíveis problemas. Isto é um alerta. Até aí tudo bem.

O segundo código não roda porque você estará pegando sujeira. A última coisa que você deveria fazer é pegar um valor arbitrário, jogar em uma variável e tentar acessar isto como se fosse um endereço válido da memória. É loteria. Programação não deve ser loteria. Isto só deveria ser ensinado para dizer para não fazer.

O código dele funcionou nas condições que ele estava usando. Não funcionará em nenhuma outra condição. O vídeo deveria alertar isto, e se não o fez, mostra como é ruim. Eu tentei e cada execução dá um endereço diferente, não tem como confiar nisto, esqueça esta maluquice. A única forma de usar um endereço fixo é algo que está documentado que sempre estará lá, o que é raro hoje em dia.

Aliás, o estilo de código apresentado também é ruim. Eu nem me preocuparia muito se estivesse ensinando quem tem uma boa noção de programação e como as linguagens funcionam. Mas eu percebo que o objetivo é ensinar leigos. Aí ele cria vícios ruins, já que os leigos costumam usar essas "aulas" como receita de bolo.

A melhor recomendação que posso lhe dar é parar de ver estas videoaulas. E nem digo só estas, quase todas são muito fracas, superficiais e na maioria das vezes incorretas ou pelo menos enganosas (em inglês tem algumas melhores).

Procure aprender por fontes melhores, que realmente ensinem a programar, como a linguagem realmente funciona. Se tiver dúvidas específicas, poste aqui. Mesmo quando alguém fala alguma besteira, aparece outra pessoa para mostrar que está errado, então você não corre muito risco de aprender errado (isto já foi melhor, hoje passam algumas coisas erradas).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É uma decisão sua, eu falei que o endereço muda todas as vezes.